# Conversion between decimal and binary operations

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Can there be a method or function that directly maps the bit operations of binary numbers to the operations of decimal integers?

For example, binary AND operations, such as 111101&1111=1101, can be directly operated on 61 to obtain 13 without converting to base

Comment: I wonder why we now see an interest in doing binary operations "without converting to binary": [Is there a way to do a bitwise AND operation on two base-10 numbers?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4754362/139123) Coincidence?

Comment: Perhaps we are encountering similar problems at the same time. What I am facing is when calculating homomorphisms in ciphertext, I want to perform AND operations. If converting to binary is more troublesome, so I am considering whether there is a direct mapping method. Thank you for letting me know that others, like me, are also facing this problem. This is cool!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may appreciate the following: write your operation as $f(x,y)$. Define $$\phi(x)=
\begin{cases}
    x/2, & x\equiv 0 \bmod 2\\
    (x-1)/2, & x\equiv 1 \bmod 2
\end{cases}$$

Then, we have

$$
    f(x,y)=
\begin{cases}
    2f(\phi(x),\phi(x))+1, & x\equiv y\equiv 1\bmod 2\\
    2f(\phi(x),\phi(x)), & \textrm{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
and $f(1,1)=1$.

So, to compute your operation recursively without first converting to binary: divide both numbers by two and return $2f(\phi(x),\phi(y))$ with an extra $+1$ if both numbers are odd.

**Ex.**

\begin{align*}
    f(21,22)&=2f(10,11)\\
    &=4f(5,5)\\
    &=8f(2,2)+4\\
    &=16f(1,1)+4\\
    &=20
\end{align*}

This works because $\phi$ is the equivalent of deleting the last bit in binary, and $x\mapsto 2x$ ($x\mapsto 2x+1$) is the equivalent of adjoining a $0$ ($1$) to the right of the binary representation.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. This method has greatly inspired me. Recursion has a higher complexity, can there be a lower complexity approach？

Comment: @zaidongLi A particular digit of the answer in decimal will typically depend on the values of many binary digits. The values of each of those binary digits depends on the corresponding binary digits of the two inputs, which each can depend on many decimal digits. This all suggests that conversion to and from binary is the most efficient way of performing the calculations. It's the most straightforward, at least.

Comment: Yes, converting base numbers is the most direct method. My idea is that if you perform ciphertext operations in a computer, multiple division and modulus operations will increase the complexity, so I am exploring a more efficient method

Comment: Unless you have a very unusual computer, all of the numbers in it are already converted to binary and it can just do the AND operation in a single step. It's unclear what actually is causing this to be difficult for you.